# ¿Cómo reproducir colecciones de una base de datos MongoDB de una aplicacion?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

Me gustaría usar el ejemplo de una aplicación de preguntas y respuestas [disponible sobre github](https://github.com/sylwolveryn/nodejs-quizzes). Sin embargo, necesito crear mi propia base de datos para esto.

Quiero ser capaz de conectarme pero pienso que necesito crear colecciones en mi base de datos MongoDB. En efecto por lo momento cuando intento crear un usuario hay espero para siempre el localhost

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parece que está sucediendo [en config/passport.js](https://github.com/sylwolveryn/nodejs-quizzes/blob/master/config/passport.js):

```
function handleLocalSignUp(req, name, password, done) {
    try {
        process.nextTick(function () {
            User.findOne({'local.name': name}, function (err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    return done(err);
                }
                if (user) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That name is already taken.'));
                }
                else {
                    var newUser = new User();
                    createNewRoleFor(newUser.id);
                    createNewAchievementsFor(newUser.id);
                    newUser.displayName = name;
                    newUser.local.name = name;
                    newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);
                    newUser.save(function (err) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        return done(null, newUser);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        done(e);
    }
}
```

Pero cuando quieres guardarlo, con el `newUser.save()`, no veo a qué función se refiere, así que en qué base de datos lo insertaré.

## Para replicar la app

Es muy simple sólo hay unos pocos pasos en el readme.

Para la base de datos pueden empezar de la siguiente manera: el desarrollador usó un simple mongodb. La capa de repositorio está en la parte de configuración: https://github.com/sylwolveryn/nodejs-quizzes/blob/master/config/mongoModule.js

Registró una simple cuenta de nivel libre de mlab y la usó. Pero mlab no parece acceder a una nueva cuenta así que probé un Atlas de MongoDB

Entonces actualizando la parte de la conexión:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOOSE_MLAB_URI || 'mongodb://sandboxUser:PASSWORD@ds011880.mlab.com:11880/quizzessandbox');
```

Pude conectarme a mi propio mongodb (vacia).

Localmente se puede usar un simple mongodb. Algunos ajustes de la base del mongodb se pueden encontrar aquí también: https://github.com/sylwolveryn/nodejs-quizzes/blob/master/mongod
Pero apenas recuerda haber implementado esta cosa que hizo para intentar el pasaporte js, oauth ...

Comment: Hola, ¿exactamente cuál es el problema? Todo lo que hay en la pregunta es una descripción (incompleta) de un procedimiento para hacer *algo*. No veo claramente ¿cuál es la duda o dificultad encontrada? ¿Cuál es el comportamiento deseado? ¿Cuál es el comportamiento actual? y ¿qué has intentado / investigado para resolverlo?. ¿Podrías aclarar más tu pregunta? Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Gracias por tu comentario, he actualizado y tratado de ser más claro. Para empezar desde algún punto de esta actualización intento registrar un nuevo usuario.